# Push Notification design layout / ask permission

Tags: css, push-notification, service-worker

In my forum users receive a push notification for new events. New users will be asked if they want to allow or deny push notifications for this page. So I would like to design this question with a custom design. I've been searching the internet for weeks on how to do this. I searched for:

- push notification ask design style
- service worker design custom
- etc.

Unfortunately, I can't find any instructions that explain how I can style this browser question. I know how to style the push notifications but I dont know how to design the question for permission. Thank you very much for a link or put me in the right direction.

I use this service worker:

```
(function() {

  function registerServiceWorker() {
    return navigator.serviceWorker.register("/notifications/push/push-notif.js")
    .then(function(registration) {
      console.log("Service worker successfully registered.");
      return registration;
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.error("Unable to register service worker.", err);
    });
  }
  
  const allOptionsNotification = function(registration) {
    const title = "Web Push Book";
    const options = {

      actions: [
        {
         
        }
      ]
    };
    registration.showNotification(title, options);
  };

 const titleAndBodyNotification = function(registration) {
   
  };

  const longTitleAndBodyNotification = function(registration) {
    
  };

  const iconNotification = function(registration) {
    
  };

  const badgeNotification = function(registration) {
   
  };

  const imageNotification = function(registration) {
   
  };

  const vibrateNotification = function(registration) {

  };

  const soundNotification = function(registration) {

  };

  const dirLTRNotification = function(registration) {

  };

  const dirRTLNotification = function(registration) {

  };

  const timestampNotification = function(registration) {

  };

  const actionsNotification = function(registration) {

    };   

  const notificationTag = function(registration) {
    
  };

  const renotifyNotification = function(registration) {

  };

  const silentNotification = function(registration) {

  };

  const requiresInteractionNotification = function(registration) {

  };

  const openWindow = function(registration) {
   
  };

  const focusWindow = function(registration) {
    const options = {
      body: "You have new notifications.",
      icon: "https://example...",
      badge: "https://example...",
      tag: "focus-window"
    };
    registration.showNotification("News on this website", options);
  };  

  const dataNotification = function(registration) {

  };

  const mergeNotification = function(registration) {

  };

  const mustShowNotification = function(registration) {

  };

  const sendMessageToPage = function(registration) {

  };

  const setUpSWMessageListener = function() {

  };
  
  const setUpNotificationButtons = function() {
    setUpSWMessageListener();

    const configs = [
      
      {
        className: "js-focus-window",
        cb: focusWindow,
        enabled: () => {
          return true;
        }
      }      
     
    ];

    return registerServiceWorker()
    .then(function(registration) {
      configs.forEach(function(config) {
        const button = document.querySelector(`.${config.className}`);
        if (!button) {
          console.error("No button found with classname: ", config.className);
          return;
        }
        button.addEventListener("click", function() {
          const promiseResult = config.cb(registration);
          if (promiseResult) {
            button.disabled = true;
            promiseResult.then(() => {
              button.disabled = false;
            })
          }
        });
        button.disabled = !config.enabled();
      });
    });
  };

  window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    if (!("serviceWorker" in navigator)) {
      // Service Worker isn"t supported on this browser, disable or hide UI.
      return;
    }

    if (!("PushManager" in window)) {
      // Push isn"t supported on this browser, disable or hide UI.
      return;
    }

    let promiseChain = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const permissionPromise = Notification.requestPermission((result) => {
        resolve(result);
      });
      if (permissionPromise) {
        permissionPromise.then(resolve);
      }
    })
    .then((result) => {
      if (result === "granted") {
        setUpNotificationButtons();
      } else {
        displayNoPermissionError();
      }
    });
  });
})();
```

Comment: Do you get any solution

Comment: Sorry, not yet. If you find something, please let me know.